# How to check the return code of Start-Process

Tags: powershell

I wan to get the the return code properly for start-process. Even if the start-process finished with error its not throwing the retun code properly. When ever I have error in the run.bat also the code for error handling is not triggered.
What is wrong in my code

Thank you for your support.

```
$errorlog = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\error.log"
$emailconnecter_log = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\connector.log"

#1  print "Running email bat file...... \n";
Write-Host "Running email bat file...... \n"
$prog="cmd.exe"
$params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')
$rc = start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus" -RedirectStandardOutput $emailconnecter_log -PassThru -wait
    if (-not $?) 
    { 
    Write-Host $rc
        $status = "running Daily email bat file failed on $hostname"
        Del_Daily
        Del_Dat
        Send_Mail
        exit
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host $rc
    Write-Host "Email send sucess fully....."
    }
```

Comment: For started processes, `$?` is not the value to query, you shold query `$rc.exitcode`.

Comment: I tried similalry with the link but as per the above code i was using  `-RedirectStandardOutput $emailconnecter_log ` and the cnsole output writing properly into the log file now it is not printing into log file. Could you help me

Comment: How to direct the working directory , i tried like `$pinfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\EmailConnector-Discover Optimus"` but the code not running, i have to explicitly break code then the code is working uptot his point

Comment: @shagi change to single quotes or escape your space character. It's likely breaking on the space in your path.